# big amount of images in jquery DataTables table

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, datatables

for example, i've got a table with nearly 1500 entries. most of them have a tiny picture. with the DataTable plugin it is really easy to setup a nice to use/filter/view table. but of course, with this big amount of images the loading speed of the page is pretty bad. does anybody know a way of loading the images just if they are in the view? 50 entries are shown at the time - there is a pagination.

i have know clue, how to combine a image loading technic with the DataTable plugin.

Any ideas? Would be pretty much amazing!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816318/jquery-lazyload-images-in-jquery-databables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "lazy loading"

Here is a [plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) but you can search for many others that are available..

Comment: Hey Emin, a lazy loading plugin is the solution for the problem - i know. But does anybody tried to combine this with dataTables? I couldn't find a way for this yet.

Comment: I think this conversation covers lazy loading in DataTables: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1959/image-thumbs-in-table-column.-lazy-loading/p1 ... Also, this page seems to suggest that this ability is built in: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf