# jquery-lazyload images in jquery-databables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-lazyload

With the [datatables javascript plugin](http://datatables.net/) I want to display 10k little images in a table with pagination.
Because I load too much of them, I get errors.

I would like to load those images only when they appear so I found the [lazyload plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

However, the images don't appear at all at first.
I have to manually enter

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

in the browser console.
Then only it loads the images that are on screen
(i.e. when I scroll down, I see all other images unloaded).
This proves at least that the plugin is somewhat working.

Is there something particular to do with the use of datatables?
Do I have to scriptually trigger lazyload every second?

Thank you !

Comment: You could also simply use lazySizes. It works out of the box with any other JS behavior: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another method [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1959/image-thumbs-in-table-column.-lazy-loading/p1) without the lazyload plugin.
Use the option

```
"fnRowCallback": customFnRowCallback
```

and then this function will replace the first column with an image tag.

```
function customFnRowCallback( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex )
{
    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html( '<img class="" src="http://aaaaa/'+ aData.attribute+'" alt="" />' );
    return nRow;
}
```