# Datatables - load only visible images

Tags: jquery, image, datatables

I have a table (~1000 rows) that has to be preloaded to the client. For each row, I would like to display an image that is fetched from a remote server.

However, loading all at once would mean 1000 requests and about 50 megabytes transferred, which is not too great.

How do I make sure Datatables displays only the images on the current page/search?

Comment: Please take the tour and read how to make a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @randy I don't think this particular example requires a code example, since the question is purely theoretical (and I answered my own question).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816318/jquery-lazyload-images-in-jquery-databables

Comment: after 7 years this question seems to be upvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's likely a way to programatically put image links in IMG tags only once the row is displayed, it's easier to just use something else.

Using [jQuery Unveil](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) simplifies the entire process in combination with Datatables' `drawCallback`. If you do not use `drawCallback` and use the default Unveil's code, image loading on search may not function correctly.

Images (in rows):

```
<img src="placeholder.png" data-src="imagetoload.jpg" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tableid').DataTable( {
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            $("#tableid img:visible").unveil();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: DId you answer your own question within one second, or what are you doing here?

Comment: @eisbehr This is well admited on SO to answer own question even if you get the answer before asking the question, nothing wrong there. This could be helpful for futur readers

Comment: @eisbehr Last I checked posting your own solutions for your own issues is not only allowed, it's [*explicitly encouraged*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @Sašo That was unclear to me. It's a strange behavior in my eyes. But I have to apologize then. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Use [jQuery.Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy). Just change your images and add a `data-src`, containing the original image, to them.

```
<img src="empty.gif" data-src="originalImage.jpg" />
```

---

```
$(function() {
    var lazy = $("table img").Lazy({chainable: false});

    $("table").DataTable({
        drawCallback: function() {
            // update the images shown on table changes
            lazy.update();
        }
    });
});
```