# Working example of datatables with lazy loading of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, lazy-loading

I'm looking for a working example of lazy-loading of images within datatables that continues to work after clicking on a column heading to change the sorting.

The method I've had the most success with uses the jquery.lazyload plug:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
    });
</script>
```

Here's how I reference the image:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="https://example.com/image.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
```

The lazy loading works fine if I never change the sorting. However, if I decide to change the sorting of the table by clicking on one of the column headings, the lazy loading stops working and any images that were not downloaded at this point will remain blank when I scroll them into view.

I wasn't born a javascript or jQuery expert, so had to learn from examples here on SO and elsewhere. But this problem stumps me. From my research, I see a lot of comments and snippets about how it is possible, but no actual working example that proves this is supported.

[jquery-lazyload images in jquery-databables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816318/jquery-lazyload-images-in-jquery-databables)

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1959/image-thumbs-in-table-column-lazy-loading

I wont rattle off the numerous other links I found here and elsewhere, I just need some kind soul to help.

Comment: If the sorting is on client side the library may be fetching the data first and would then resort to sorting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to define a function that will be called every time DataTables performs a draw.

For example:

```
$('.table-data').DataTable({
   drawCallback: function(){
        $("img.lazy").lazyload();
   }
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx8aq7zu/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks @Gyrocode.com, I was able to get it working after looking at the source code of your jsFiddle. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much for this. So the key issue I had was that my <img tags were using src="" rather than data-original="".  The jsFiddle helped very much so thanks for taking the time to share.

Comment: How to use this in angular 7

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of stuck with this one seeing as I don't have access to your backend or more information about your circumstances but I think what will work will be to call your lazy load code in the draw event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
    $('.table-data').DataTable({
        "drawCallback": function(){
            $("img.lazy").lazyload();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(window).trigger("scroll")
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

I've got an example up [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lzga6jxt/), but I think you might be using server-side processing?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @annoyingmouse. I tested your jsfiddle and with Chrome inspect tool open, it appears to fetch all images before they come into view, ie not doing the lazy load correctly. I could be mistaken though as I'm new to using the Chrome developer tool! Yes, doing server-side processng. The backend prepares an HTML file that looks similar to what you created, only difference being that it uses **data-original** instead of **src** and it has width/height attributes. I switched this to replicate your example but instead of lazy-loading, all images are downloaded.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've fixed it so that the scroll event is triggered after the draw event.

Comment: I've checked the answer from @Gyrocode.com and that's correct. The setTimeout isn't required after all! Ahh well - at least you've got your working example! :-)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @annoyingmouse. I managed to get it working after looking at Gyrocode's jsFiddle. I'm very happy to have a working example at last! :)